# Cypress: check if browser is in full screen mode

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, integration-testing, cypress

Is there anyway to check if the browser is in full screen mode in Cypress?

More than that I think that when I run my tests, the full screen functionality does not work. Do you know if it's something supported by Cypress?

Answer (score 1):

Remember, any changes that you make to configuration using this API will only be in effect for the remainder of the tests in the same spec file.

```
{
  "viewportWidth": 1280,
  "viewportHeight": 720
}
```

Comment: Hmm sorry but this answer doesn't seem to address the question. Ruben Aguilar is asking if it's possible to check if browser is in fullscreen but your answer only provides an option to set the width/height for the viewport. I fail to see how it's anything but useless.

Answer (score 0):

To check if Cypress is running on fullscreen you can get the viewport dimensions using [`Cypress.config`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config.html#Name-and-Value) and check if those are the same as the device's screen size.

To run Cypress on fullscreen, you should be able to change the viewport dimensions to the size of the screen using [`cy.viewport`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/viewport.html#Syntax) (I haven't tested this out, but it should work).

Comment: This does not work, because Chromium will not permit fullscreen unless it is triggered by a user gesture. And there does not seem to be a command-line flag or any other way of changing that, other than modifying Chromium.
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1213

Comment: So, Cypress doesn't have an built-in function to maximise the execution screen (viewport). And it doesn't have other basic things, that Python front end testing has had for a long time.